# Make regex from string with unicode characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
alphabet = unicode("abś", 'utf-8');
```

How can I convert it to:

```
"ab\\u015B";
```

? I tried that code:

```
al = ""
for char in alphabet:
    if ord(char) > 127:
       al += "\\u" + format(ord(char), 'x')
    else:
       al += char
```

But when I want to make regex from that, it doesn't matches properly chars:

```
abc = re.compile(u'[' + al + u']{1,}$', re.U).match
```

Demo is here: http://ideone.com/q55HI8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> u"abś".encode('unicode-escape')
'ab\\u015b'
```

I think you can get what you want without any transformation of original unicode string:

```
>>> abc = re.compile(u"[abś]{1,}$", re.U).match
>>> abc(u"ś")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x89f31a8>
>>> abc(u"ś").group()
u'\u015b'
>>> abc(u"a").group()
u'a'
>>> abc("x") is None
True
```